# Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I keep getting this error even though I increase the timeout value. I'm currently mocking a spreadsheet service and my mock looks like this:

```
const mockSpreadsheetService = {
  insertNewRow: async (doc, newRow) => {
    await doc.loadInfo();
    await doc.sheetsByIndex[0].addRow(newRow);
    return newRow;
  },
  readSpreadsheet: async (id) => {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(id);
    let private_key = process.env.SERVICE_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY;
    private_key = private_key.replace(new RegExp('\\\\n', 'g'), '\n');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
      private_key,
      client_email: process.env.SERVICE_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    });
    await doc.loadInfo();
    return doc;
  }, 
};
```

readSpreadsheet works perfectly fine, but once i call it inside insertNewRow, i keep getting this error thrown.

My test currently looks like this.

```
describe('insertNewRow', () => {
    it('adds a new row to a spreadsheet', async () => {
      const doc = await mockSpreadsheetService.readSpreadsheet(spreadsheetId)
      await mockSpreadsheetService.insertNewRow(doc, newRow)
      expect(newRow).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
```

I tried increasing the timeout but it still keeps happening and I really don't seem to understand what the problem is, as I believe i have all my async/await's where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "testTimeout": 15000,
  }
```

This should increase your test timeouts to 15sec